# Site lost design after copying it

Tags: magento-1.8, database

I created a copy of my project for testing. First I duplicated the whole folder and renamed it from "test-foo" to "test-bar".

Then I exported the database and imported it (which was very time consuming because there were many timeouts).

Then I changed the file "app/etc/local.xml" to point to the new database.

However, this is how my site looks now:

[image]

It seems like it lost the design or does not point to the correct one?

How can I fix this?

Also If I try to enter the backend, then I get redirected to the original site which I have copied, even though I changed "web/secure/base_url" and "web/unsecure/base_url" to point to the new URL.

I also get `The current marker does not contain a unique ("unique") column.` (translated from german...) inside Phpmyadmin, on every table of the imported database, and I can't edit anything until I execute e.g. `ALTER TABLE`core_config_data`ADD UNIQUE (`config_id`)`

Comment: Did you try removing the cache and session directory under magento_root/var? Also check .htaccess on magento root and permission to the magento directory.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Good hints. I cleared the cache but no difference. I think I know the way. The problem is that I accidentially copied the wrong database, I will check and report back.

Comment: Great. Let me know if you still have issue.

Comment: Check CSS/JS merge enabled in admin.

Comment: I think it was either because I copied the wrong database or because of my fix. Fix: I used Notepad++ to search the whole exported database SQL file for the old Domain URL and replaced it with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I think it was either because I copied the wrong database or because of my fix.

Fix:
I used Notepad++ to search the whole exported database SQL file for the old Domain URL and replaced it with the new one, then I imported it.